# Script to run a secure file and then delete it

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to create a script to copy a secure exe file to the C directory from a flash drive that is assigned the drive letter D. Then to run the exe, delete the exe, then shut down the PC. I have technicians who need to do this in order to make a biometric reader function properly. They keep screwing up the process and I would like to automate the process to save me a headache. The file is secure and cannot be leaked to our customers due to licensing. I already tried a batch script, but the exe doesn't seem to launch correctly.

Here's what I had:

```
COPY "D:\Biometric\software.exe" "C:\software.exe"

Pause

pushd C:\

Start "C:\software.exe"

Pause

pushd C:\

erase "software.exe" /F /Q

Pause

c:\windows\system32\shutdown -s -f -t 00
```

I've never tried VBScript, and I figured maybe that might get me the results I need, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A problem with your code is that you'll try to delete it before it finishes running because you are running it with start. Start is unnecessary in this situation and means don't wait for the program to finish. `c:\software` is all that is required.

Answer (score 2):

`Start` considers the first set of quotes it finds to be the window's title, so what you have in your code essentially says "set the window's title to 'C:\software.exe' and then execute the `start` command on nothing."

Insert an extra set of quotes to make the start command work.

```
start "" "C:\software.exe"
```